# merging dataframes only by certain columns

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I try to merge dataframes by index and only take certain columns to the result.

```
result = pd.concat([self.retailer_categories_probes_df['euclidean_distance'], self.retailers_categories_df['euclidean_distance']])
```

But with the result I get the 'euclidean_distance' from first table ?
Any idea what is wrong ?

Also how I can give names to the destination columns ?

Comment: What's the structure of the dataframes you're merging?  And what exactly is going wrong?  Are you not getting the data from the second dataframe?  Is there an error message?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you may need `axis=1`:

```
result = pd.concat([self.retailer_categories_probes_df['euclidean_distance'], self.retailers_categories_df['euclidean_distance']], axis=1)
```

See `pd.concat()` [docs](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.concat.html)